# Laravel select box, display database value by default

Tags: php, laravel, select

I'm using a select box in laravel

```
<td>{!! Form::select('statCode', array('A' => 'Yes', 'D' => 'No')) !!}</td>
```

statCode is a column in the database table that this reads and writes to and I have it in the controller as `$i->statCode`

Is there a way I can modify this so that it shows the `$i->statCode` as the default value of the select box? Currently it just shows 'Yes' by default so if I save with the select box as 'No' it reflects the change in the database but if I go back in to edit it the box is back to 'Yes' as the default and I want it to always show the database value as the default.

The database holds either 'A' or 'D' so if the database value is 'A' i want 'Yes' to show, if it's 'D' I want 'No' to show

Comment: Which package you are using for Form?

Comment: Just the default laravel forms where you would use form::open, etc.

Comment: I guess the laravelcollective/html package. It was used in the Laravel versions previous 5.*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3d parameter is the default value, so you can use it like this:

```
{!! Form::select('statCode', array('A' => 'Yes', 'D' => 'No'), old('statCode', $i->statCode)) !!}
```

This will reflect even if you submit the form and there is an error, the previously selected state will be checked.